# Laravel Nova Custom Fields get model value

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I created a custom field for Nova.
On this field I need to get some extra model data like `$model->country` to show on the form.
How can I pass this data to the Vue component?

I try to use:

```
return $this->withMeta
```

But I don't know how to pass the data from the model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the custom field like a normal field to the resource `fields()` and chain a custom method with the data from the model:

```
CountryField::make('Country')->country('Germany'),
```

Define this custom method in your Nova component (see `src` folder):

```
public function country($value)
{
    return $this->withMeta([
        'country' => $value,
    ]);
}
```

You can access the returned data from this method in `FormField.vue` like this:

```
{{ field.country }}
```

Comment: @Sven  Can you please look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57053896/laravel-nova-custom-field-set-value-based-on-another-field-and-still-editable) question and give some idea?

Comment: But how do you fill 'Germany' with the actual value that is in the model so you can use it in Vue?